# Grunt Modernizr doesn't add css classes

Tags: gruntjs, modernizr

Hello I want to use Grunt Modernizr. It works in my javascript. But the script doesn’t add Css Classes? Does anybody know why?

```
modernizr: {
        prod: {
            parseFiles: true,
            customTests: [],
            devFile: false,
            dest: '<%= path.jsSrc %>build/modernizr.min.js',
            tests: [
                "input",
                "inputtypes",
                "touchevents",
                "css/flexbox",
                "css/flexboxlegacy",
                "css/flexboxtweener"
            ],
            extensibility: [
                "domPrefixes",
                "prefixes",
                "mq",
                "testAllProps",
                "testProp",
                "testStyles",
                "html5shiv",
                "setClasses"
            ],
            extra: {
                "mq" : false,
                "cssclasses" : true
            },
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= path.cssSrc %>**/*.scss',
                    '<%= path.jsSrc %>*.js',
                    '<%= path.jsSrc %>libs/*.js'
                ]
            },
            uglify: true
        }
    },
```

I don’t see no-flexbox for example on my html

Comment: Can you post the URL generated on the top of the file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I replaced "extensibility" with "options", so try this:

```
options: [
    "domPrefixes",
    "prefixes",
    "mq",
    "testAllProps",
    "testProp",
    "testStyles",
    "html5shiv",
    "setClasses"
]
```

Check out the customizr readme : 
https://github.com/doctyper/customizr